# Why components defined by "customElements.define()" are not globally usable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, web-component

I am working on a **Svelte** project, but it contains some web components.

The issue I am facing is that some web components defined by the `customElements.define()` **Typescript** function are not usable unless I import them specifically in the user component.

For example, a web component is defined in the following way:

```
// File name is oneWebComponent.js
export class OneWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    ...
    customElements.define('one-web-component', OneWebComponent);
}
```

Then, there is another JS file, which contains a "factory" function that creates different types of Web Components:

```
export const createElement = (tagName) => {
    return document.createElement(tagName);
}
```

If I call it like `createElement('one-web-component')`, the resulting component is not really the one defined in `OneWebComponent`. I know that because the functions defined there are not callable (error: XXX is not a function).

But if I import `oneWebComponent.js` in the factory file like below, it works correctly:

```
// This line is newly added:
import './oneWebComponent.js';

export const createElement = (tagName) => {
    return document.createElement(tagName);
}
```

That means, if I have multiple types of web components, and the factory function is called in multiple places, I will have to import each type of web component in each place, which is tedious.

I wonder if there is a way to just make the components defined by `customElements.define()` **globally usable**?

That means, no imports needed, just passing the tag name into `document.createElement()` and it will create the web component correctly.

Am I missing any configs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `customElements.define('one-web-component', OneWebComponent);` statement inside the `class` definition is a syntax error. What are you actually doing?

Comment: "*if I `import 'oneWebComponent.js'`, it works*" - well if you *don't* import the module anywhere, the `customElements.define()` call is never executed. You don't have to import in the module that defines the factory function, it could be imported anywhere (globally!) - once is enough.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. I didn't import the web components anywhere... That is what I meant by "missing any configs". I should just import them in the root component, like `app.svelte` Thanks so much.

Comment: An answer should be added and accepted, or the question deleted, if it is deemed unhelpful.

Comment: (Make sure to accept it once you are allowed to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bergi pointed out, the `customElements.define()` function is not executed if the file is not imported anywhere.

So I only needed to import all of the web components in the top level of the app, a file like `app.svelte` or `main.js` for example, then the function will run, and the tags are defined and usable across the app.